# Grab X-CSRF Token to login with php/curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to log into a website via php/curl that uses an X-CSRF token for authentication.  Looking at the headers in Firefox with LiveHttpHeaders I can't see the token being passed via cookie in any GET requests... it seemingly just appears in the header of the POST login request as well as the POST login fields.  Any ideas as to how to login into a site via php/curl that uses these tokens?  How do I go about grabbing the token and including it along with my username and password in the post_fields curl_setopt?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem here... the token is passed in an html meta tag rather than via header or cookie.  Parsing the html via preg_replace for the token did the trick!